# get date of adding to wishlist in magento

Tags: php, magento

I know magento several days. Can somebody help me to find solution to get date of adding to wishlist. I would like get this information in template/wishlist/item/column/info.phtml
i have tried like

```
$item = $this->getItem();

$product = $item->getProduct();

Var_dump($product->_data)
```

but  without success.
The object $product has date of adding to wishlist but is protected.

Comment: Why do you load the product to the item? Try `$item->getAddedAt()` (see `Mage_Wishlist_Model_Item`).

Comment: @SimonH. You can write that as an answer. It's correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The date of adding the product to the wishlist is stored in the wishlist item. Try to use `$item->getAddedAt()` instead of loading the product (see Mage_Wishlist_Model_Item).